# Django tests freeze randomly if celery broker is not running

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, unit-testing

#### The issue

When running unit tests locally, at a certain point in time, it totally freezes, and I can't understand what's wrong.
I have no clue even if I run tests with the maximum verbose `-v3` option.

I think it can't be related to the tests themselves, because they used to pass, or they still pass in a CI. Plus, it does not always freeze at the same stage.

[image]

#### What I uses

- Docker for mac 2.2.0.3
- on MacOS 10.15.3
- with PostgreSQL official image (10.12)
- psycopg 2.7.7

#### What I tried

- I tried to run tests on another computer with Docker
- I tried to comment the test that freezes, but then it will freeze somewhere else
- I tried to change PostgreSQL version locally
- I tried to run tests using other options like `--reverse` or `--parallel`

Any idea? How to debug this?

Comment: If you wait for an additional 5 minutes does it eventually run fine?

Comment: One possibility is locking in the database - [this page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) has some queries for detecting locks.  It may be possible that a failing test leaves a lock on a table, causing a later test to hang.

Comment: @snakecharmerb -> Thanks, I'll take a look. However, how would it explain the non-deterministic behaviour?
Ngoc-Tin Daniel Nguyen -> Nope, frozen forever.

Comment: If the test freezes forever, it's almost certainly waiting on a lock.  As for deterministic behaviour, the tests always hang, so that's deterministic :-)  Seriously though, if a test leaves a lock or open transaction on, say, the users table, then the next test that tries to get a lock on that table will hang.  The order of tests is irrelevant, as long as the test that leaves the lock runs before a test that requires a lock on  the same table.

Comment: @snakecharmerb it seems you gave me the right track to follow thanks ;) I get some rows that appears in PG locks when tests are frozen. Now I need to understand why, then I'll update my question/answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Ok I feel stupid, but it could help some folks so...

-> If you're using Celery, and your tests call some tasks using `delay()` method, ensure your broker server is running (in my case I use Redis). If not, it will freeze anything in your code since it seems there is no timeout when the redis client tries tu connect to the server.

Comment: Just saying, you can use the always eager mode, so you don't need to run the workers and broker.

Comment: Or if you don't need to run the celery code, you can mock the celery method.